# Re-purpose USB cable to carry I2C

Tags: atmega, i2c, cables, atmega32u4

I was wondering if it would be possible to connect an IO extender (MCP23017-E/SP) to an ATMega32u4-AU via an USB cable.

I figured that if you connect up the SCL pin to the Data+ of the USB and the SCA pin to the Data- of USB, ground the 4th pin and power the 1st it should work.

Am I correct with this?

Image example in Kicad schematic:

[image]

Comment: It should work for short distance cable. Bus capacitance may be addressed by reducing the I2C speed to minimal if possible.

Comment: @Umar how short of a distance are we talking about here? Haha. I was planning on having it run through about a 6inch to 1 foot cable.

Comment: That should do.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no problem.  The original [Nunchuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Nunchuk) for the Nintendo Wii game system connected to the Wii Remote via a **1 to 1.2m** (**3.5 to 4 feet**) long cable, very similar to a USB cable (six pin connector, but only four were used). The Nunchuk contained a a 2-axis joystick, two buttons and a 3 axis ±2g accelerometer and used a I2C interface to communicate with the remote, running at 100 kHz as documented [here](http://www.britishideas.com/2011/08/20/reading-a-wii-nunchuck-using-i2c/) and [here](http://free-electrons.com/labs/doc/nunchuk.pdf).  Sparkfun even sells a little [breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9281) for hobbyists building their own interfaces.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!  Ill be using it to  run a 5x7 matrix for a keyboard :) should be easy.  Might get more complicated if I do LED's in a future batch. But thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Where are the pullup resistors for SDA and SCL ?

The problem with I2C is cable capacitance (already mentioned), crosstalk between SDA and SCL, pullup resistors and voltage differences.

Are both running at 5V ? Then that is okay.
You can use pullup resistors at the Master of 2k2 for SDA and SCL.

It is only a short cable, so it should be possible.
You could try the [MultiSpeed I2C Scanner](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=197360.0). It it runs at 400kHz, then 100kHz or is very safe to use.

Comment: I have updated it. Added pullups resistors just to be safe. It will already be running at 5v. So there shouldn't be any problems at all.

Comment: No guarantees, but it should work. Run that test with 400kHz. As a backup plan, the Wire.setClock can be used to lower the speed to 50kHz.